# How to find highest value from an array, if there are more than one high value?

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array which I would like to find the highest value for, **but this value might be repeated**.

For example, consider this array of integers:

```
{10, 2, 6, 25, 40, 58, 60, 60}.
//Here the value 60 is repeated
```

Here, I would like the output to show that there are two highest values in this array. Like in upper example it have to be show that 60 is highest value among all values in array and that value is 2 time available in array. And i do not want like to count how many numbers but like addition of that two highest numbers. I have search programs but i could not find any relevant solution for this.

```
class Cal
{
    void CalculateThis()
    {
        int[] myArray = new int[] {20,10,5,40,20,41,41,2,6,7,3,4,5,6,23,34,7,8,9,2};
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int sum=0;
        for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
        {
            if(myArray[i] > max) 
            {
                 max = myArray[i]*3;
                 sum = sum + max;
             }
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }

}


class program1
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Cal obj = new Cal();
        obj.CalculateThis();
    }
}
```

Comment: share whatever you have tried till now.

Comment: Please post what you have so far. We are not doing homework for you without you showing some effort.

Comment: "And i do not want like to count how many numbers but like addition of that two highest numbers." What do you mean? Do you mean in *all* cases you want the sum of the two highest numbers, even if they're not equal?

Comment: I want that result like sum of total number of highest values from an array. @JonSkeet

Comment: Have you had a look at this [link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaCollections/article.html#collectionssort) ? If you change your `int`-Array to an `Integer`-Array you can call `Collections.sort()` on it and then just sum up.

Comment: @RonakJoshi just to clarify: **in the example with the two 60s, do you want the number 120?** Also, **what do you want `CalculateThis()` to print?**

Comment: @RonakJoshi: So if there are three equal highest values, you'd want the sum of all three? It would help if you would give various examples with expected output.

Comment: @StefanFreitag: There's already `Arrays.sort`...

Comment: @Ronak Joshi check my solution. Hopefully it is want you want

Answer (score 0):

```
int max = ar[0];
int maxSum = 0;
for (int i=1; i< ar.length; i++)
{
    if(ar[i] > max)
       max = ar[i];
    else
       if(ar[i] == max)
          maxSum+=max;
}
```

Comment: That's finding the count, which apparently *isn't* what the OP wants. Oh, and you're never declaring or initializing `max`, *or* resetting `maxCount` when changing `max`. With "1,2,3,4,5,6" your code would report a max of 6 and a count of 6.

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] myArray = { 10, 2, 6, 25, 40, 58, 60, 60 };
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int maxCount = 0;

for (int x : myArray) {
    if (x > max) {
        max = x;
        maxCount = 1;
    } else if (x == max) {
        maxCount++;
    }
}
int maxSum = max * maxCount;

System.out.println("Max value : " + max);
System.out.println("Max Count : " + maxCount);
System.out.println("Max Sum : " + maxSum);
```

output :

```
Max value : 60
Max Count : 2
Max Sum : 120
```

Comment: Note that this will fail for an array consisting solely of `Integer.MIN_VALUE` elements. You might want to change the first condition to `if (maxCount == 0 || x > max)` - then the initial value of `max` doesn't matter.

Comment: @JonSkeet you would still get the count properly however in finding total sum there would be a problem due to integer overflow.

Comment: True - had failed to spot that we'd just increment as normal. Multiplication would be okay for a single element array :)

Answer (score 0):

There are various approaches you could take here:

- Sort the array using `Arrays.sort`, then work from the end until you saw a different value... letting you work out the value and the count, which you could then multiply together. This is relatively inefficient, as you don't really need to sort.
- Write two methods, one of which returned the maximum value and one of which returned the count of a specific value. Find the maximum first, then the count of that, then multiply together. This requires two passes, but is clean in terms of building the final result from separate and reusable operations.
- Write a method to keep track of the `max` and the `sum` at the same time, resetting *both* if you see a higher value. This will probably be the most efficient, but wouldn't be reusable for other requirements. (You could equivalently keep track of a `count` as you went, and multiply the `max` by `count` at the end instead.)